# What is the differences between the mapping arguments?

Tags: vim, mapping, vi, vim-plugin

What are the actual differences between typing:

1. `:map <script> , dd`
2. `:map , dd`
3. `:map <buffer> , dd`
4. `:map <script> <buffer> , dd`

I am much more concerned with `<script>` arguments. In which cases we need to use the argument  `<script>`

Comment: you have read the related help doc, haven't you?

Comment: Yes concerning 2 and 3 it is clear for me and the difference between them when they coexist but when comes to add `<script>` argument I cannot understand really what it means.

Comment: I think the doc is clear enough, the `<script>` mapping works only locally to a script.. which part don't you understand?

Comment: `<buffer>` works only locally to a buffer but the script is also a buffer so what is the difference ? and what is meant by script is it every file finishing with `.vim` ?

Comment: No. The script is not a buffer.

Comment: Then could you please define the word script ?

Comment: Any `*.vim` file is a vim script by definition where functions and commands have been defined. A buffer contains the text you are editing. It may be a (vim) script, but in this situation, it's unrelated.

Comment: so in other words every script is a buffer and a buffer cannot be always a script. `<script>` argument is used only in scripts to be executed locally then it is useless to type `<script> <buffer>` ?  and this script will be sourced in other buffers so those remapping with <script> arguments do they have effect in those buffers ? if yes so why do they call them locally  we can use <buffer> instead ; if not when are they going to have effect if they are limited to scripts ? still confused !!

Comment: `every script is a buffer and a buffer cannot be always a script` I don't think this statement is correct. @Sabrina

Comment: I meant that a buffer can be a usual file.

Answer (score 3):

in short, **buffer**, is in mem text of your file, which you can see by `:ls` and edit. **script**, could be loaded by vim as well, however you cannot see it in `:ls` command. E.g., you create vim file, say `foo.vim`:

```
 function! s:SayHi() abort 
      echo "Hi, there"
 endfunction
```

And in your `vimrc` file, you source the `foo.vim`, now there is a script scope.  The mapping with `<script>` will make the `{rhs}` call other mapping, **which is defined in same script**, even if with `nnoremap`.

An example perhaps is better. Say the same `foo.vim`, we have two mappings:

```
nnoremap <SID>foo dowhatever 
nnoremap abc <SID>foo
```

in this way, `abc` won't eventually go to `dowhatever`, because of the `nore`. However

```
nnoremap <SID>foo dowhatever 
nnoremap <script> abc <SID>foo
```

This will overwrite the `nore` rule, `abc` will reach `dowhatever`. but only if the first mapping was defined in the same script.  (`nnoremap <script>` and `nmap <script>` are doing same)

Personally I don't think `<script>` map is really useful.

Comment: Still confused but the example gives some lights to the arguments.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス confused about script & buffer? or what?

Comment: The argument `<script>` too.

Answer (score 1):

A "script" is a bunch of related Ex commands and vimscript functions put together in a `*.vim` file.

Upon startup, Vim sources a number of "scripts". It means that it executes each line in each script just like if you wrote it in the command-line yourself. Additionally, Vim keeps track of what was sourced where with the `<SID>` mechanism. "Scripts" are used *internally* by Vim to provide additional functionalities.

The meaning of the `<script>` argument is clearly explained in `:h <script>`:

> If the first argument to one of these commands is "`<script>`" and it is used to
>   define a new mapping or abbreviation, the mapping will only remap characters
>   in the `{rhs}` using mappings that were defined local to a script, starting with
>   "`<SID>`".  This can be used to avoid that mappings from outside a script
>   interfere (e.g., when CTRL-V is remapped in mswin.vim), but do use other
>   mappings defined in the script.

A "buffer" is the in-memory representation of the content of a file. Think of it as a "document" in regular programs.

When you edit a "buffer" and you define a `<buffer>` mapping, that mapping will only be available in that specific buffer.

Going with your examples:

```
" - remapping is possible but only with other
"   mappings defined in the same script
:map <script> , dd

" - mapping is global
" - remapping is possible
:map , dd

" - mapping is buffer-local
" - remapping is possible
:map <buffer> , dd

" - mapping is buffer-local
" - remapping is possible but only with other
"   mappings defined in the same script
:map <script> <buffer> , dd
```